# Is it possible to implement spell-check functionality using Redis as dictionary and AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, dictionary, redis, spell-checking

I have implemented a search functionality that searches the typed query against my database (or redis) and retrieves the results. The records which are fetched are names and not some standard terms which appears in dictionary. So I cannot use conventional spell-check functionality of HTML to check typed words against dictionary.

Therefore,Is there a possibility to use Redis as dictionary and make a custom spell check using Angularjs? If there is any helpful source, please share.

Comment: theoretically yes. but don't ask me how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course it is possible however you will have to write a few lines of code yourself. You can use [this](http://www.varunpant.com/posts/auto-complete-with-redis-python) link as a reference.